# side sliding menu tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to implement a right  side sliding menu similar to the one in [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com)..
i am trying to use javascript to edit the script on every mouseover/onclick event.. 
i want to hide/show the table on every event.

```
function show(a){
    var id="myMenu"+a
   if (i<-12){
        i=i+speed;
        document.getElementById(id).style.left=i;
    }
}
function hide(a){
    var id="myMenu"+a
    if (i>-135){
        i=i-speed;
        document.getElementById(id).style.left=i;
    }
}
```

this should be good to show/hide the tables.. but how to id dynamically add two tables one over another..because the main menu table will always be visible, but the sub menu when hidden will be beneath the main menu..

any method to do the same? 
am i in the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely on the right path, this is a good test of concept.

I would suggest you look at jQuery (or other JavaScript libraries like Scriptaculous) specifically at the `slideToggle()` and `toggle()` methods.

Don't want to give it all away, but take a look at the Amazon source code, you may get some helpful little tips. :P

Comment: i believe you mean JavaScript (or ECMAScript), not Java... Java is a different beast entirely ;)